# How do I set a max numeric value in a Devexpress TextEdit box?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, textedit

I've got a numbers-only TextEdit box with `MaxLength` set to 2, allowing the user to enter 0-99. Can I restrict this to a smaller range, say 0-30, without catching the `TextChanged` event, validating the input and showing a messsage (or similar method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the regexp mask to `\d|[0-2]\d|30`.

Comment: perfect, nice and simple and I don't need to rebuild my control set. If I were starting from scratch I may not have gone for the regex solution though :)

Comment: Personally, I just set the Mask type to `d0` and then write validation code to only allow the numbers I want, with a clear message about the range limits if the user types something invalid. That's personal preference though.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `SpinEdit` control and set the max and min properties.

Comment: As I said on @Blindy's answer - the SpinEdit is easier to set up without regexes so is a better solution overall, but as I asked specifically about TextEdits I thought I would give Blindy the marked answer

Comment: @Alex Don't forget that you can use a SpinEdit and hide the up/down buttons to give a TextEdit appearance, as per this: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q476112

Answer (score 0):

Handle the EditValueChanging event,

```
private void txtQuantity_EditValueChanging(object sender, ChangingEventArgs e)
{
    var value = Convert.ToDouble(e.NewValue);
    if (value < MIN || value > MAX) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In winforms you should use System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown and set the Maximum and Minimum properties.